# How to refer to already found column in a Sheet formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA problem. I have a code a which finds a column and then it inserts a worksheets formula in another column. The formula contains a reference to the previously found column.

```
Dim intBB As Integer
Dim rngBB As Range
Dim controlBB As Integer

intBB = 1

Do While Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, intBB) <> ""
        If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, intBB).Value = "BbCode" Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                Set rngBB = .Range(.Cells(2, intBB), .Cells(2, intBB))
                controlBB = intBB
             End With
         Exit Do

        End If
          intBB = intBB + 1
    Loop


Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("W3:W2500").Formula = "= _
IF (controlBB="""","""",BDP(controlBB&"" Equity"",""ID_ISIN""))"
```

However, this does not work. How can I correctly refer to the found column?

Comment: you could "clean-up" your code bu putting the `Worksheets("Sheet2")` in the begining.

Comment: controlBB is a integer not a column reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a column number, rather than letter, I'd suggest using R1C1 format:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("W3:W2500").FormulaR1C1 = "= _
IF (RC" & controlBB & "="""","""",BDP(RC" & controlBB & "&"" Equity"",""ID_ISIN""))"
```

Comment: Man you were fast!

Comment: Really fast , are you getting the questions before the rest of us ;)

Comment: I may have mild psychic abilities. ;)

Comment: @Aeneas Are you using `Formula` or `FormulaR1C1`?

Comment: @Rory Sorry it works now. Had a space in wrong place

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
For i = 3 To 2500
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a" & i).Formula = "=IF(" & Cells(i, controlBB).Address & "="""","""",BDP(" & Cells(i, controlBB).Address & " & "" Equity"",""ID_ISIN""))"
Next i
```